# Yelp Search API issues

Tags: yelp

This is yelp search API.

Used [this api](https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?categories=restaurants,spanish&latitude=10.315699&longitude=123.885437) for getting spanish restaurants. And it gives me nearly 150 restaurants, but most of them are not Spanish Restaurant Category.

```
id": "zubuchon-cebu-city",
"name": "Zubuchon",
"image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/7F3B5-2LfivkII9d5i8iaA/o.jpg",
"is_closed": false,
"url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/zubuchon-cebu-city?adjust_creative=jO7FkmyPhUkuDm8uD3-6gA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=jO7FkmyPhUkuDm8uD3-6gA",
"review_count": 13,
"categories":[
{"alias": "filipino", "title": "Filipino"},
{"alias": "seafood", "title": "Seafood"},
{"alias": "soup", "title": "Soup"}
],
"rating": 4,
"coordinates":{"latitude": 10.317542, "longitude": 123.894127},
"transactions":[],
"price": "₱₱",
"location":{"address1": "N Escario Street", "address2": "Escario Central", "address3": "", "city": "Cebu City",…},
"phone": "+63322540247",
"display_phone": "+63 32 254 0247",
"distance": 972.4964813519999

...
```

How can i filter only Spanish Restaurants?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add it into the url parameter. I am using python and I just add

```
url_param = { 
              'term': 'Spanish',
              < other params here >
            }
```

to my request